# Using Linq, Trying to Use OrderBy on Object's Children

Tags: sql-server, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-entities, c#-4.0

Trying to use Linq with some Entity objects to do a crafty query here. Hoping for some help with a point I'm having a hard time finding decent documentation on:

Basically, I'm trying to use OrderBy to order against the child of an object I'm querying against. The difficult part is that the object has multiple children, and based on the object's type, I need to use one set of a children or another set of children to order by.

To clarify:

A can come in two types: i, or ii

If A is of type i, then I need to order by D: i.e, A has a B, which has many Cs, which has many Ds.

If A is of type ii, then I need to order by F: ie. A has an E, which has many Fs.

So the question is, how can I order by D and F, from A?

I'm hoping for something like:

```
IQueryable<AObject> aObj = query.OrderBy(aObject=> aObject.Type==i? aObject.B.C.D : aObject.E.F).Skip(offset).Take(limit).AsQueryable();
```

Of course, I'm also just confused as to how to order the D's, when C has a collection of Ds

Thoughts? And thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you include an example of what specifically you are looking for? It's OK to use the real class names. That might make it easier to explain.

Comment: The class names actually don't help - they're rather abstract entities, and I'd have to first give a lesson on the business model in order to make sense, heh heh :). A similar relationship I guess could be Bloggers, and Users. Say you fetch blog posts via Users. Users of type Blogger have Blogs, Blogs have Posts, and you want to sort by Post Timestamp. Users of type Reader have Subscriptions which contains Blog Posts they have read, which you want to order by Read date. For the sake of the example, one can only be a Blogger or a Reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an aggregate function such as [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548741.aspx) or [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534962.aspx) to pick a value that represents the collection and use that value for the ordering. For example:

```
IQueryable<AObject> aObj = query.OrderBy(aObject =>
    aObject.Type==i ?
    aObject.B.Cs.Max(c => c.Ds.Max(d => d.Foo)) : 
    aObject.E.Fs.Max(f => f.Bar)
).Skip(offset).Take(limit).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Hm, can you explain the use of Max? Wouldn't Max just return the largest D, and then by ordered by the largest D? To use numbers, if the largest D was 10, wouldn't OrderBy by ordered by 10? That makes no sense to me...

Comment: @AlishahNovin: It's not "ordered by 10", it's ordering by the result of the lambda function. The function is evaluated once per element so for one element you might get 10, the next element give 12, the next 9, etc... Then these values will be used to order the elements (in this case 9, 10, 12).